# How can I make requests from a different device to a server hosted on my machine?

Tags: server, request, backend, asp.net-core-webapi, httprequest

I want to allow people on the same network as me to make requests to a backend I'm running (It's an `ASP.NET Core` web API but I don't know if this is relevant).When I make requests from my PC, I only need to use `localhost` and the port the server is running on (which I know). I don't know what is the URL that they should use.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you will host your web app. Usually, we will host it in IIS and [using self-host application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314393/7687666).

But we need to pay attention, because we generally use the personal version of the windows operating system, such as win10 or win11, if you use websocket in your web app, it will be limited by 10 connections. Due to the lack of a domain name resolution server, it cannot be accessed using a custom domain name. Access can only use ip+port to access web app.

*Url should like below:*

```
http://192.168.1.X:80
```

All we need to do is allow the port to be accessed in the firewall settings.

---

**Tips:**

If you want your application to be accessed remotely, we can use intranet penetration technology, such as frp or ngrok.

Comment: Where can I look up what the exact URL is? How do I know what to put instead of X?

Comment: @stack_overflow_nickname https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IIJV.png

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I added inbound and outbound rules for the port my web API runs on. Yet, my coworker (who is on the same network) could not connect to it.

Comment: @stack_overflow_nickname  [Try this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359161/7687666)

Comment: Sorry, but I am reluctant to share those.

Comment: @stack_overflow_nickname, Under normal circumstances, it should be an intranet ip like 192.168.

Comment: If you have more error details, you are very welcome to share them with us.