# ASP.NET Core 6 cors policy by IP

Tags: axios, cors, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a cors policy like this:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    //builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();  //it's working
    builder.WithOrigins("http://192.168.0.109:8000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); //not working
    builder.WithOrigins("http://192.168.0.109:8000","http://192.168.0.109:8000/").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); //not working
}));
```

I am trying to post the data from axios.post from react js form, my server and port config is

`vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        host: '192.168.0.109',      -- not working
        port: 8000

        //host:'localhost',          --if i change the host and port to localhost & 3000, it works fine
        // port: 3000
    }
})
```

Axios post command:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5220/api/Auth/register", userData)
```

Comment: When you change to `192.168.0.109`, do the client side and server side application in the same machine ?

Comment: @jasonpan yes, both are in the same machine

Comment: @jasonpan `192.168.0.109` is my laptop local ip, then only i can test the from mobile and tab which is connected on same network. If i run on `locahost`, I couldn't access from other devices

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359161/7687666